Necessary steps to rename parachain
Due to rebranding we'd like to change our parachain (project) name as well as token symbol, however, I'm not 100% sure what can/can't be changed.
We'd like to keep using the current parachain (so the same paraId, as we don't want to launch a new chain), but with as many parts updated with new information as possible, as long as they are allowed to be changed.
My understanding is:
things that can be changed/updated:

token symbol in chain spec
SS58Registry info (name, token ...)
polkadot-js app info (logo, name, color, endpoint ...)

things that can't be changed:

spec_name in runtime
impl_name in runtime

Is my understanding correct?
What about the name, id, protocol_id in the chain spec? Is it safe to change them?


The impl_name can be modified as needed.
The ecosystem is moving towards deprecating SS58.
Regarding the chain spec, refer to https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/cdf3a2dc1385debf50096d54d4abf838c6cad4f7/substrate/client/chain-spec/src/lib.rs#L389-L427. These changes won't impact the runtime, but you must ensure they are no longer in use. For example, if you have id = "foo", and some code like if spec.id().starts_with("foo") { spec.load() }, you'll need to review and update such instances yourself.

